# Aptana gives error with JSON format

Tags: json, aptana

Format:

```
{
    "lastUpdate" : "20/9/2012-12:12",
    "data":[{
        "user" : "_name_",
        "username" : "_fullname_",
        "photoURL" : "_url_"
    }, {
        "user" : "_name_",
        "username" : "_fullname_",
        "photoURL" : "_url_"
    }, {
        "user" : "_name_",
        "username" : "_fullname_",
        "photoURL" : "_url_"
    }]
}
```

Aptana gives errors at the `:`

[Screenshot Aptana JSON format](http://postimage.org/image/vix8i4u6d/)

Why is that? It seems I'm not having any problems receiving and processing the data.

[EDIT 1] Error given: Syntax Error: unexpected token ":"

Comment: No the extension was .js. I changed it to .json (thnx) but that didn't solved the errors

Comment: uhh Huh... After some time that did solved the errors. Strange it doesn't solved them immediately. Thanks again. (add it as solution and ill accept it, as i can't vote your comment yet) **EDIT** not after some time. After closing and reopening. Well thats something that make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Aptana json is parsed "as json" only when you create/open a file with extension .json.

When have a json object inside a .js file works only the javascript parser, for that you see the error, is not a valid token for JS.